# Why can C++ const references be collasped into non-const references

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(T& x) : x_(x){}
    const T& get() { return x_; }

private:
    T x_;
};

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    A<int&>(x).get() = 43; // compiles fine, even though get() looks like it returns a const ref
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

The program compiles OK and outputs 43. This suggests that the seemingly const reference returned by get() is in fact a *non-const* reference, because it allows to modifies the value it refers to.

Is it a rule of reference collapsing that causes this behaviour?

How to enforce that the reference returned from get() behaves like a const reference, that is, it doesn't allow to modify the value it refers to?

Comment: Reference being const vs the object being referenced being const.

Comment: My knowledge of C++ is pretty dated, but `A<int&>(x)` seems odd.  Why is that not just `A<int>(x)`

Comment: In this case `get()` returns a reference to a const reference to an int. Can you assign an `int` to a const reference to an `int`? Sure you can. It's not a reference to a const int, it's a const reference to an int.

Comment: @hauron No, it's returning `int&`.

Comment: @DaveGoldberg That would defeat the purpose of the question which is about reference collapsing.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Does that even make sense? We can't have const references just as we have const pointers, we can only have the referenced object be const. Or is this a C++ corner case?

Comment: @Rakete1111 you're right, this is indeed a "const reference" to a "reference to int".

Comment: You can demonstrate this behavior in much less code: https://godbolt.org/g/vcET76

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it a rule of reference collapsing that causes this behaviour?

[Yes](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6). You have:

```
T = int&
const T& = const (int&) &
```

References can't be `const` (you can't rebind them anyways, so it's ignored) and a reference to a reference is just a reference.

So you have

```
const T& = int&
```

To fix this, you need to apply `const` to the underlying type, which you can do like this by removing the reference:

```
const std::remove_reference_t<T>& get() { return x_; }
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I suggest to rephrase this for clarity: `T = int& --> cont T& = T const& = int& const& = int&`. When dealing with types compiler works "from right to left"; `const T` is an unfortunate C-ism that C++ inherited.